# Macvim - how to prevent tab names being abbreviated?

Tags: macvim

In macvim, is it possible to make tab names full length (i.e. not shortened?)

e.g., If I open `a-very-really-quite-long-file-name.txt`, its name in the tab is shortened to `a-very-really-q...`. This is frustrating if you open several files open with long names, which are similar at the start. (In console vim, this shortening doesn't happen).

Is there an option or setting which prevents this shortening?

(My option `guitablabel=%M%t` where `%t` is the file name (the docs don't seem to mention shortening), and I'm using macvim 7.3.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an ok solution at http://code.google.com/p/macvim/wiki/UserDefaults
You can make the tab labels wider with the following code typed into a terminal ($ signs are prompts, don't type them):

```
$ defaults write org.vim.MacVim MMTabMinWidth 200
$ defaults write org.vim.MacVim MMTabOptimumWidth 300
$ defaults write org.vim.MacVim MMTabMaxWidth 400
```

Where you can change the numbers (which are pixel widths) as you like. It's not a perfect solution -- tab label widths are not dymnamically sized to the file name length. So it you open a really long file name, too wide even for the extra wide setting you made, you will still get abbreviation & dots.

If anyone knows a better solution, I'd be keen to hear it ...

Comment: I think the link is broken, it just goes to the main github page of macvim.